# Convergence of sequence that can't be solved for n

Tags: real-analysis

The sequence in question is

$$(a_n), \text{where } a_n = \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} \text{ for } n\in \mathbb{N}$$

and I'm supposed to use definition 2.2.3 from Understanding Analysis by Abbott, which says that a sequence $a_n$ converges to a real number $a$ if for every positive $\varepsilon$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for every $n\geq N$ we have $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon$.

The book shows various examples where we simply solve the general term of the sequence for $n$ and then show that everything works. The problem with this exercise is that I can't solve for $n$ explicitly. I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to use the squeeze theorem as the book hasn't mentioned it yet, so I'm kinda out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^{2}}{n^{3}+3}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2/n}{1+3/n^{3}}=\frac{0}{1+0}=0.
$$
This tells us that the limit should be $0$. Now we prove it.

First fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N>2/\epsilon$. Then we observe that for $n\geq N$, 
$$
\left|\frac{2n^{2}}{n^{3}+3}-0\right|=\left|\frac{2n^{2}}{n^{3}+3}\right|\leq \frac{2n^{2}}{n^{3}}=\frac{2}{n}\leq \frac{2}{N}<\epsilon.
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}<\frac{2}{n}$$ for $n>0$
Additionally you Can write $$\frac{\frac{2}{n}}{1+\frac{3}{n^3}}$$ so $$\frac{2}{n}$$ and $$\frac{3}{n^3}$$ tends to Zero for $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: Can I just take for granted the fact that if a "bigger" sequence than $a_n$ converges, then $a_n$ also converges? The book hasn't mentioned it yet, although it's obviously true.

Comment: That's... the squeeze theorem. *"I'm not supposed to use the squeeze theorem as the book hasn't mentioned it yet, so I'm kinda out of ideas."*

Comment: For further ideas see the post above!